# Return an angular $resource from a factory after an asynchronous function call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

Return an angular $resource from a factory after an asynchronous function call.

Below shows an example of an angular factory in which I'm attempting to return a $resource.

I'm trying to make an asynchronous function call using another service to receive the web service path before returning the $resource.

Is this possible?

```
angular.module('app').factory('newService', function($resource, configService) {
    configService.get(function(config) {
         return $resource(config.webServicePath + '/api/names', {},
             { 'update': { method:'PUT' } }
         );
    });
});
```

Would anybody have an example of either a service, provider, or factory returning a resource after an asynchronous function call to receive information like above.

It would also be helpful if you could provide an example of the newService being used in a controller.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: "return" and "asynchronous" don't usually mix. You want to be working with promises, and callbacks. Angular has a service named `$q`, see http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q. Most angular requests return promises already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

currently, it's the callback that's returning the `resource`, which doesn't help you much.  You can't delay a return statement until an async function has completed, but you can work with [$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q) promise.

```
ngular.module('app').factory('newService', function($resource, configService, $q) {
    var resourcePromise = $q.defer();
    configService.get(function(config) {
        resourcePromise.resolve($resource(config.webServicePath + '/api/names', {},
            { 'update': { method:'PUT' } }
        ));
    });
    return resourcePromise.promise;
});
```

Here's how `$q` works

1. You need to return a value that you get in the future, so you defer it using `$q.defer()`
2. This returns a deferred object.
3. You make your async call, and in its success callback, you call `.resolve` on the deferred object.
4. If the callback fails, you call `.reject`on the deferred object.
5. You return `deferredobject.promise`, which is a promise object.

**Using a service that returns promises**

When you expect a value from a promise, you can listen for it by passing a callback to its `then`method. If the promise might be rejected (the operation failed), it's a good idea to pass a second callback, which will be called when the promise is rejected.

Here's a simple example of a service that returns a promise, and how to use it:

http://jsfiddle.net/rP5Gh/